# Array Memory allocation in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, v8

I am dealing with a huge array,

It contains ~200,000 elements. Basically its a **array of strings.** Each string being ~50 characters in length. After looking around I found it would take 2 bytes for 1 character, i.e 100 bytes for 1 element.

**therefore, the total memory allocation should add up to `200,000 * 100 = ~20 MB`**

[object-sizeof](https://github.com/miktam/sizeof#readme), [js-sizeof](https://github.com/andyburke/js-sizeof/blob/master/index.js), [sizeof](https://github.com/lyroyce/sizeof) seems to implement same logic.

But consider this snippet,

```
process.memoryUsage();
const paths = getAllFilePaths();
process.memoryUsage();
```

Output before getting array,

```
external:25080
heapTotal:31178752
heapUsed:10427896 //10 MB
rss:51761152
```

Output after getting array,

```
external:16888
heapTotal:173539328
heapUsed:134720896 //134 MB
rss:204070912
```

This is ~124MB addition to `heapUsed`.

Implementation of `getAllFilePaths()`:

```
const getAllFilePaths = function (_path, paths = []) {

    fs.readdirSync(_path).forEach(name => {
        const stat = fs.lstatSync(joinPath(_path, name))
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            getAllFilePaths(joinPath(_path, name), paths);
            return;
        }

        paths.push(joinPath(_path, name));
    });

    return paths;
};
```

Why is so much memory being used ? Is this the desired behaviour or somehow `getAllFilePaths()` function could possibly be leaking memory ?

Comment: What exactly is `getArray()`?

Comment: It could be that the method you use to build this Array of strings, is deep-nested as such, makes use of other resources, etc.

Comment: Please mention the implementation of your getArray() function

Comment: ```getArray()``` is a recursive function that traverses a directory path and returns all the nested filepaths.

Comment: please see updated question.

Comment: Well seeing this could be that `lstatSync` returning `fs.Stats` recursively, it just builds up in memory depending on the directories you traverse before the method is done.

Comment: Interesting test (I know it might sound wierd) but try copy paste the paths into a list, assign it hard-coded into a variable and run the test again, see if there's a difference in the memory footprint.

Comment: What is the host operating system that node.js is running on?  You shouldn't need to concern yourself with memory management when using JavaScript, but the way the operating system manages memory is a concern, Windows isn't great, Linux is better.

Answer (score 4):

V8 developer here. Two points come to mind to explain the discrepancy between your expectations and measurements:

(1) An array of strings needs more memory than just the strings' characters. In memory, a string object has a header that takes 16 bytes on a 64-bit system (a pointer-sized[1] "shape" pointer plus two 32-bit fields for hash and length). Depending on how exactly the strings are constructed, they might also use different representations internally; header + characters is the simplest form. Additionally, the array itself has a pointer-sized entry for each element, adding at least another 200,000 * 8 bytes = 1.5MB -- dynamically-grown arrays over-allocate when they have to grow so that they don't have to grow for every addition, which can waste space if the array is unlucky enough to stop growing right after having over-allocated.

(2) AFAIK `process.memoryUsage()` simply returns the current heap usage statistics, which can contain garbage left behind by previous operations. To determine the memory consumption of something, it is advisable to explicitly trigger a full GC cycle before every measurement. Specifically: start Node with `--expose-gc` and call `global.gc()` before every `process.memoryUsage()`.

For completeness, I'll mention: strings can take 1 or 2 bytes per character depending on their contents. Per individual string, each character takes the same amount, so a single non-ASCII character forces the entire string to be two-byte. For embedder-provided strings (like file names), the embedder also has to play along to support the one-byte optimization; I don't know whether Node's file API does this.

[1] "pointer-sized" means 64 bits = 8 bytes nowadays; with "[pointer-compression](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-80)" becoming available in V8 8.0 this shrinks to 4 bytes (if you choose to deploy a pointer-compressed build).

Answer (score 1):

Did a small test here: [Memory Leak Test](https://repl.it/repls/NavyblueNutritiousRate)

This seems to show that 200,000 items of 50 chars hardcoded into an array outputs the following:

```
{ 
rss: 58232832,
heapTotal: 40378368,
heapUsed: 25490136, // ~25 MB
external: 8272 
}
```

Comment: This is more than likely not quite conclusive, since the string is hardcoded, and could be potentially optimized out, but interesting to see.